# Add element's children to jQuery set without leaving the chain

Tags: jquery, addition, composition, traversal

Is there a possibility to add the children of elements in a jQuery set to the set without leaving the chain?

I.e., *with* leaving it would look like this:

```
var set = $('.some-elements');
set.add('*', set);
// or immediate ones only
set.add(set.children());
```

I'm looking for a way to do any of these without creating the interim `set` variable:

```
$('.some-elements').jqMagic("*");
```

(Of course one could write a "jqMagic" plugin for this. I just want to be sure, there isn't this functionality in jQuery core.)

Comment: do u add children on some event?? like `click` or `change` or watever.if yes then see the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: You could start the chain with `set` (I would not create a plugin just to save one line of code). The only other way is to use `$('.some-elements')` again...

Comment: Correction: It's not the only way ;) Only if you think in one direction, i.e. getting the "parent set" first and then adding the children. But it works by selecting the children first and then adding the parents again, as @Nathan shows...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [AndSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) will let you do what you're asking.

**update with example:**

Given the following html:

```
<div id="1" class="testdiv">
   <a href="#">test a</a>
   <a href="#">test b</a>
</div>


<div id="2" class="testdiv">
    <a href="#">test c</a>
    <a href="#">test d</a>
</div>
```

This code gives just the children (anchor tags in this case) a red border:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $('.testdiv').children().css('border','solid 1px red');

</script>
```

while this code (using andSelf()) includes the parent divs in the element list and therefore selects both the parent divs and the child divs - thus giving a merged set as you requested:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $('.testdiv').children().andSelf().css('border','solid 1px red');

</script>
```

Comment: @Felix Kling - example provided :)

Comment: Thanks... my mind was twisted, that's why I couldn't see how it should work... but taking a step back sometimes does wonders ;) (I wrote another comment before which I deleted...)